# Default text for null value with knockout bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the same observable for display and edit views as follows. I would like a default text ('-') to appear in the display view whenever the return value is `null`, but I do not want that in the edit view. How could that be achieved?

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.txt1 = ko.observable();
  self.txt2 = ko.observable();
}
```

```html
// View Mode
<span data-bind="text:txt1"></span>
<span data-bind="text:txt2"></span>

// Edit Mode
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt1" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach to `computed`s as per my other answer is to write an entire new [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).  This means you only have the one observable on your view model, with the logic contained within the binding handler instead.  Note that you need to change the view to use this binding handler, rather than the `text` binding it was using:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.textdefault = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var v = valueAccessor();
    var d = allBindings.get('defaultIfBlank') || '-';
    element.innerText = (v() == null || v() == '') ? d : v();
  }
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.txt1 = ko.observable();
  self.txt2 = ko.observable();           
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
// View Mode<br />
<span data-bind="textdefault:txt1"></span><br />
<span data-bind="textdefault:txt2, defaultIfBlank: '$'"></span><br />
<br />
// Edit Mode<br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt1" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt2" /><br />
```

Note that in this approach, we can also customise the handler through the `allBindings` variable - in the above I have added a parameter to allow customising of which character is displayed if the entry is blank.

Comment: I got Javascript runtime error: unable to set property 'textDefault' of undefined or null reference. note the the i load the display text through ajax call

Comment: @stacknist I'd need to see more of your code to advise - as you can see in the live snippet here, this approach should work and answers your initial question.  If you're having problems with something else, feel free to ask a new question once you've researched/debugged etc!

Comment: Nice answer. I think a better name for your binding would be just `placeholder`.

Comment: @Andrea Yeah - obviously can be changed to anything you want, I didn't choose `placeholder` for this answer since someone may confuse it with the `placeholder` in your answer, but yes it would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most paradigmatic Knockout.js solution but it's working well and it's very quick.
Instead of the `<span>` you could use an HTML `<input />`, with `placeholder="-" readonly="readonly"`. You may want also to style it so that you hide borders.

```
<input class="readonly" data-bind="value:txt1" readonly placeholder="-" />
<input class="readonly" data-bind="value:txt2" readonly placeholder="-" />
```

```
.readonly {
    border: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbf3uxqe/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`computed` observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to return a value for the view mode, using it to check the value currently stored and return `-` if necessary:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.txt1 = ko.observable();
  self.txt2 = ko.observable();

  self.viewtxt1 = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.txt1() == null)
      return '-';

    return self.txt1();
  });

  self.viewtxt2 = ko.computed(function() {
    //txt2 is checked for null or blank, use whichever is appropriate
    if (self.txt2() == null || self.txt2() == '')
      return '-';

    return self.txt2();
  });
                              
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
// View Mode<br />
<span data-bind="text:viewtxt1"></span><br />
<span data-bind="text:viewtxt2"></span><br />
<br />
// Edit Mode<br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt1" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="value:txt2" /><br />
```

In the above there are two different checks.  `txt1` is checked just for `null`, and so if you edit it and delete all characters, the blank value will persist in the view.  `txt2` is checked for both `null` and blank, so removing all characters will reset the view back to `-`.  Use whichever one is appropriate to you.

Comment: This solution seems good but I would like to maintain the same observable for display view and edit view input. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @stacknist I've added an alternative approach using a custom binding handler in another answer.